# scifi horror movie/episode involving an alien emerging from a dimensional gate

Tags: story-identification, aliens, horror

I vaguely remember channel surfing in the late 90's and seeing a horror movie scene in which a woman emerges from a portal/gate/wormhole and says something like "there's thousands of them!".

She is suddenly impaled from behind, and an alien's insectoid head appears over her shoulder. She is then dragged back into the portal.

I was called away from the TV at that point, but the scene has stuck in my mind as an example of a pre-CGI monster/alien, and I remember thinking that the creature effects looked too expensive for a TV show.

Answer (score 5):

This [review/summary](http://www.bmoviegraveyard.com/reviews/S/Shadowzone/) of [Shadowzone (1990)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100586/) sounds like it matches your memory.

> A few seconds later **she emerges from the column of light,
>   evidently having stepped through to the other side**. Her hands seem to
>   be glowing with power. **She looks at the Captain and yells, “there’s
>   thousands of them!”** Her words are cut short by the pipe she just
>   pushed into the gateway a few seconds earlier. It has now been brought
>   back through by John Doe and **used to impale Erhart through the back
>   and out her chest**. She bleeds some from the mouth, but doesn’t utter
>   another sound until she dies an instant later.
>   The shitty-looking (and I mean that literally, the thing looks like it
>   is comprised of a series of turds stacked atop one another into a
>   vague humanoid form) John Doe now grasps the Doctor from behind, and
>   using the pipe lodged in her body as a handle, **pulls her back into the
>   portal**. Apparently these people don’t like visitors who drop in
>   unannounced and then just as quickly leave. They want her back.